# The effect of the world sheet parity reversal

Tags: string-theory, parity

(D Branes Clifford V. Johnson Page 105)

> The action of world sheet parity reversal is to exchange $X^\mu(z)$ and $X^\mu(\bar z)$.

However, I don't quite follow what kind of parity reversal it was. Is it

\begin{equation}
z\rightarrow -z, \bar z \rightarrow -\bar z
\end{equation}
which was the same as
\begin{equation}
\tau\rightarrow -\tau, \sigma \rightarrow -\sigma
\end{equation}
?

Either, in the mode expansion,
\begin{equation}
a_{-n}^\mu =(\frac{2}{\alpha'})^{1/2} \oint \frac{dz}{2\pi} z^{-n} \partial_z X^\mu(z)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar a_{-n}^\mu =(\frac{2}{\alpha'})^{1/2} \oint \frac{dz}{2\pi} \bar z^{-n} \partial_{\bar z} X^\mu(\bar z)
\end{equation}
the mode obtained a $(-1)$ sign change, but and this did not seem to exchange $X^\mu(z)$ and $X^\mu(\bar z)$.

The zero mode term $a_0$ was multiplied by $\tau$ and $\sigma$, so the zero mode terms actually stayed the same.

While the oscillator term did obtain a minus sign from $a_n$, it's still $a_n$, not $a_{-n}$, where the Fourier basis $e^{-in(\tau+\sigma)}\rightarrow e^{in(\tau+\sigma)}$, not $e^{in(\tau-\sigma)}$ for $n>0$.

Why the effect of the world sheet parity reversal is to exchange $X^\mu(z)$ and $X^\mu(\bar z)$?
[Somehow the laptop wasn't showing latex correctly, it's possible there a typo in the post.]

Comment: For the open string only even number of $n$ exchange the sign and the zero mode $\ln(-z)$ didn't quite make sense since the theory was defined on the UHP.

Comment: Exchanging $z$ with $\bar{z}$ trivially exchanges $X(z)$ with $X(\bar{z})$. You're looknig for a calculation where there is none.

Comment: @ConnorBehan What did you mean? In the target space it was usually termed as $\vec x \rightarrow -\vec x$, but in the world sheet space it was ?defined? to be the exchange of $z\leftrightarrow \bar z$ or $\sigma \rightarrow -\sigma$? Is it "one sided" parity operation? and why?